# How to deserialize JSON date time from MongoDB to C# class

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I'm using c# driver to interact with mongoDB.

I have a class that I created and which I populate with the data I get from mongoDB.
One of the properties in that class is DateTime.

The value I get from mongo is /\Date(number)/. Which is ok because this is what I'm suppose to return to the client.
The value that I get from mongo after I retrieve the data is ISODate(some number).
I get an exception: *"Invalid JSON primitive: ISODate"*.
How can I configure mongoDB to save the DateTime like I got it i.e. /\Date(number)/?

Sorry L.B - I didn't noticed your answer but went straight to the answer I was given.

Here's the class I'm trying to deserialize:

```
public class EventDate
{
    public EventDate()
    {

    }
    public int? VenueConfigID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
    public string DisplayDate { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ShortNote { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I deserialize it:

```
mongo = MongoServer.Create();
mongo.Connect();

db = mongo.GetDatabase("productionDB");
var col = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("eventDates");
var query = Query<PerformerDates>.EQ(ev => ev.PerformerID, performerId);
//MongoCursor<BsonDocument> performer = col.Find(query);
MongoCursor<BsonDocument> performer = col.FindAll();

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<EventDate> finalMatchedDates = new List<EventDate>();
foreach (var p in performer)
   {                     
       //System.Threading.Tasks.Task<EventDate[]> obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<EventDate[]>(p.Elements.ToList()[3].Value.ToString());
       EventDate[] obj3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventDate[]>(p.Elements.ToList()[3].Value.ToString());           
   }
mongo.Disconnect();
```

**Solved!!**
Eventually I solved it. I used a string instead of a DateTime. When I get it from the DB, I convert it to a DateTime and when I sent it back to the client I serialize it with the format of: /\Date()/

Comment: Where is your json? what is the definition of your class you want to deserialize to? See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Where is your code? How are you trying to deserialize it?

Answer (score 2):

Just use BsonSerializer.Deserialize method.
MongoDB's serializer has a much higher performance over NewtonSoft's Json.Net or Microsoft's DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score -1):

Very common occurring problem! One solution is to use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043412/deserialize-json-object-datetime) for more help. Although you might be confused with JSON DateTime object but don't worry. It will work!

```
string json; // Assign JSON here.
var v = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(json);
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer.
I'm using JSON.NET but didn't think of using the method you showed.
Well first, I don't get an exception now but how can I see the deserialized value?

Comment: sure, I see the object but I don't see how can I drill down to the results. I only see null in the 'results' field.

Comment: Doesn't v.toString() or Console.WritLine(v.toString()) give you insight of the object?

Comment: It just gives me:
v.ToString() -> "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[EventDate[]]"
EventDate[] is the type of values I should get.

Comment: db = mongo.GetDatabase("ProductionDB");
var col = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("eventDates");
var query = Query<PerformerDates>.EQ(ev => ev.PerformerID,performerId);
MongoCursor<BsonDocument> performer = col.FindAll();        
foreach (var p in performer)
{
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<EventDate[]> v = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<EventDate[]>(p.Elements.ToList()[3].Value.ToString());
}
mongo.Disconnect();

Comment: Eyarr!!!! Print it on a text file or on a Console. Hit breakpoint here and place your pointer there. A "plus(+)" sign will allow you to drill down:)

Comment: Hi,I know how to drill down :-) I just meant I can't find the results when I expand the results object.

Comment: Any ideas? I saw that the DateTime field is the cause for the exception and there's nothing else but this thing because I removed the field and it works

Comment: @Avi, you ask for *ideas*, but doesn't post relative infos. Read my comment under your question posted **6** hours ago.