# Error de-serializing the object of type DateTime - does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have stable web-api solution and I am accessing api methods from MVC controller using  HttpWebRequest.
GET and POST working fine without Date Time object.But when data returned from web api has Date then I am getting below error

> "There was an error deserializing the object of type Contracts.AppointmentInfo[]. DateTime content '2014-09-18T11:00:00' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON"

I haved chcked this link
[DataContractJsonSerializer - Deserializing DateTime within List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266435/datacontractjsonserializer-deserializing-datetime-within-listobject)
 but they refer to converting List of objects, but in my case I have Response from HttpWebRequest.

Here is my code , inputSerializer is input to web api method and works fine, but outputSerializer fails because it has DateTime in the resultset.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(endpoint);
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = method;
var inputSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
var outputSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T[]));

var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
inputSerializer.WriteObject(requestStream, pun);
requestStream.Close();

var response = request.GetResponse();
if (response.ContentLength == 0)
{
     response.Close();
     return default(T[]);
 }

 var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 var responseObject = (T[])outputSerializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
        responseStream.Close();
        return responseObject;
```

I have also tried to read response from HttpWebRequest as below, but does not work

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[response.ContentLength];
responseStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
string output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

and output string came like this

```
      [{\"id\":190,\"CalendarId\":1,\"CustomerId\":52,\"AppointmentDate\":\"2014-09-18T11:00:00\",\"start\":\"2014-09-18T11:00:00\",\"end\":\"2014-09-18T12:30:00\"
```

**Resolved**

I have made below change and its working

```
        Stream resstream = response.GetResponseStream();
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = resstream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0);
        {
            Response.Write(sb.ToString() + "<br/><br/>");

        }
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        T[] responseObject = ser.Deserialize<T[]>(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Brian, added part of JSON

Comment: For whatever reason DataContractJsonSerializer serializes dates differently than other Json serializers.  You'd likely be able to replace DataContractJsonSerializer with Json.Net JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>({serailizedData}).  The other option would be to do something like this post suggests.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043412/deserialize-json-object-datetime

Comment: does Json.Net JsonConvert.DeserializeObject takes response from HttpWebRequest?

Comment: I don't know all the overloads off the top of my head but obviously serialized data is a string so just read you HttpWebReponse into a string and then deserialize that string.