# Content '\/Date('')\/' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf

I want to send a post request to a WCF rest service as you can see:

```
Guid id;
id = Guid.NewGuid();

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {       
        id = id,
        Subject="wfwf",
        ViewerCounter="1",
        Content="fsdsd",
        SubmitDatatime="2012/12/12",
        ModifiedDateTime="2012/12/12",
        PublisherName="sdaadasd",
        PictureAddress="adfafsd",
        TypeOfNews="adsadaad"                       
    });

    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
try 
{ 
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch(Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
}
```

But I get an error - 400 bad request. So I traced my WCF log file and I found this error:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type CMSManagement.Domain.Entity.News. DateTime content '2012/12/12' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON.

After my dear friend @svek code. The result is like this:

```
Guid id;
id = Guid.NewGuid();

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        id = id,
        Subject = "wfwf",
        ViewerCounter = "1",
        Content = "fsdsd",
        SubmitDatatime = "2012/12/12",
        ModifiedDateTime = "2012/12/12",
        PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
        PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
        TypeOfNews = "adsadaad"
    }, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
try 
{ 
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch(Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
}
```

But I get the same error. Why?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14044014/35142) may inspire

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Use JsonConvert

Instead of using the

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( new {...} );
```

use

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {...} );
```

---

## Setting up the DateTime format

> Prior to Json.NET 4.5 dates were written using the Microsoft format: "/Date(1198908717056)/". If you want to use this format, or you want to maintain compatibility with Microsoft JSON serializers or older versions of Json.NET, then change the [DateFormatHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateFormatHandling.htm) setting to MicrosoftDateFormat.

*Source: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm*

#### Default Json.NET 4.5 Format

```
// default as of Json.NET 4.5
string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
// { "MyDateProperty":"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z" }
```

> #### Microsoft Date Format
>
> ```
> JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
> {
>     DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
> };
>
> string microsoftJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
> // { "MyDateProperty":"\/Date(1234656000000)\/" }
> ```

#### JavaScript JSON Format

```
string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, 
    new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
// { "MyDateProperty":new Date(1234656000000)}
```

---

## Solution Code

Here is the full working solution for your question:

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    id = id,
    Subject = "wfwf",
    ViewerCounter = "1",
    Content = "fsdsd",
    SubmitDatatime = "2012/12/12",
    ModifiedDateTime = "2012/12/12",
    PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
    PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
    TypeOfNews = "adsadaad"

}, microsoftDateFormatSettings); // ⇦ Added the format argument here

using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, json);
}
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0426 The type name 'SerializeObject' does not exist in the type 'JsonConvert' test_WCFService C:\Users\TFS-Symfa.UNION\Desktop\test_WCFService\test_WCFService\Form1.cs 49

Comment: Yes thanks you code works ,but i got same error in wcf tracer

Comment: What about the end of your post ?Should i add?

Comment: Now i have this problem dear friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227923/rest-service-wcf-post-null-object-in-json

Comment: You know when i changed the code base on you solution i delete this streamwriter ,so when i add this code i get the same error .I mean the problem is remain

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Why are you deleting the streamwriter?

Comment: It was my fault

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Please accept the answer if this is correct. Thanks. (Maybe delete the unneeded comments too, to be considerate to other readers.)

Comment: Thank you .Could you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: could you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228201/post-object-to-a-wcf-rest-service-in-json-returns-namespace-error

Comment: You should change the heading to **"Use JsonSerializerSettings "**, not "Use JsonConvert". Many people are already doing that, but your solution works because you explain how to add the additional parameter that points to the MicrosoftDateFormat.

Comment: This post helped me figure out how to change the I needed for a Swagger API calling an internal WCF RestAPI.  I had a property in the WCF API that is DateTime.  Since Swagger generated the code I was baffled how to set the DateFormatHandling property.  Then I found it has a partial function UpdateJsonSerializerSettings.  My fix is to add the format to the setting.
    partial void UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        // Set it to use Microsoft Date Format Settings:
        settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
    }