# Post object to a wcf rest service in json returns namespace error

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am trying to add a `news` object to my database using wcf-rest service as you can see:

```
Guid id;
id = Guid.NewGuid();

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    Id = id,
    Subject = "wfwf",
    ViewerCounter = "1",
    Content = "fsdsd",
    SubmitDateTime = "2012/12/12",
    ModifiedDateTime = "2012/12/12",
    PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
    PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
    TypeOfNews = "adsadaad"

}, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, json);
}
try { 

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
}
catch(Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
}
```

But it returns bad request 400 .so I traced the error in WCF log and I found this:

```
Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''.
```

here is my service code :

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/AddNews", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool Add(News entity);
```

And

```
 public class NewsRepository :INewsRepository
    {
        private readonly DataContext _ctx;
        public NewsRepository(DataContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public bool Add(News entity)
        {
            try
            {
                _ctx.News.Add(entity);
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
```

And my news model

```
[DataContract]
public class News
{
    [DataMember]

    public Guid Id { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public string Subject { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public int ViewerCounter { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public string MainContent { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public DateTime SubmitDateTime { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public string PublisherName { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public string PictureAddress { set; get; }
    [DataMember]

    public string TypeOfNews { set; get; }//etelaeie ya khabar



}
```

Changed code

```
 Guid id;
            id = Guid.NewGuid();

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new News()
            {
                Id = id,
                Subject = "wfwf",
                ViewerCounter = 1, // removed the "" (string)
                MainContent = "fsdsd", // renamed from "Content"
                SubmitDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
                PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
                TypeOfNews = "adsadaad"
            }, microsoftDateFormatSettings);

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, json);
            }
            try { 
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            }
            catch(Exception er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
            }
```

But same error

Comment: Could you provide more information on the receiving end? In particular your service. `http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews`

Comment: @Svek thank you Svek .I updated the question

Comment: The `News` model also, Thanks.

Comment: @Svek Again updated question

Comment: http://dotnetcodeforu.blogspot.in/2013/12/pass-json-string-data-to-rest-service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution :

```
   News student = new News
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Subject = "wfwf",
                ViewerCounter = 1, // removed the "" (string)
                MainContent = "fsdsd", // renamed from "Content"
                SubmitDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
                PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
                TypeOfNews = "adsadaad"
            };
            WebClient Proxy1 = new WebClient();
            Proxy1.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializerToUplaod = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(News));
            serializerToUplaod.WriteObject(ms, student);
             Proxy1.UploadData("http://localhost:47026/NewsRepository.svc/AddNews", "POST", ms.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mismatched types

At the moment your anonymous type has the following properties

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string ViewerCounter { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
public DateTime SubmitDateTime { get; set; }
public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
public string PublisherName { get; set; }
public string PictureAddress { get; set; }
public string TypeOfNews  { get; set; }
```

Which does not match your expected type of `News`

```
public class News
{
    public Guid Id { set; get; }
    public string Subject { set; get; }
    public int ViewerCounter { set; get; }
    public string MainContent { set; get; }
    public DateTime SubmitDateTime { set; get; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { set; get; }
    public string PublisherName { set; get; }
    public string PictureAddress { set; get; }
    public string TypeOfNews { set; get; }
}
```

#### Quick Fix

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    Id = id,
    Subject = "wfwf",
    ViewerCounter = 1, // removed the "" (string)
    MainContent = "fsdsd", // renamed from "Content"
    SubmitDateTime = "2012/12/12",
    ModifiedDateTime = "2012/12/12",
    PublisherName = "sdaadasd",
    PictureAddress = "adfafsd",
    TypeOfNews = "adsadaad"
}, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

---

#### Suggestion

To make your code easier to manage, you should make sure that you are sending across the same type whenever possible (in this case `News`). At the moment you are sending an anonymous type to the service, which may be the culprit to your issue...

So you should start off with changing

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ... }); // anonymous type
```

to

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new News { ... }); // News type
```

---

Comment: Thank you .I updated the question .I changed all you said .But same error is returned

Comment: Here is the data of variable json  in the code:{"Id":"3654fdf8-98b0-43b2-96b7-a25743ce7cb6","Subject":"wfwf","ViewerCounter":1,"MainContent":"fsdsd","SubmitDateTime":"\/Date(1496030199891+0430)\/","ModifiedDateTime":"\/Date(1496030199891+0430)\/","PublisherName":"sdaadasd","PictureAddress":"adfafsd","TypeOfNews":"adsadaad"}